# Is there a Raster2pgsql GUI?

Tags: postgis, raster

Has anyone ever attempted to create a raster2pgsql gui (like the shp2pgsql gui).

As I am sometimes lazy to use command line, this could be a very nice to have.

Comment: Easy to do with VB.net / C#. Compile the command line from the windows/options and use shell() to execute the command.

Comment: @ Michael:  Pity I do not know anything about programming.  Would have liked to be able to do that on my own though.

Comment: Now would be a perfect time to learn. Search for Visual Studio Express (the free one) and follow a tutorial. I've always found that working to a task is better than just trying to learn for the sake of learning, and take it from me it doesn't get much more basic than this. Unfortunately this is only available on windows platform, if you're linux or mac then there may be simple forms you can use.