# GUI for raster uploads to PostGIS/PostgreSQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgis-raster, raster2pgsql

We can currently upload raster data with raster2pgsql to our PostgreSQL db.

I am wondering if anyone is working on a GUI or plugin, maybe even through QGIS, that would make the raster upload process easier and more efficient for less experienced GIS users?

Comment: A GUI more efficient? Scripting is almost always more efficient and GUIs often hide details and don't expose all options. GUIs have their uses, of course.

Comment: Thank you, I agree scripting is more efficient computationally however a GUI would be easier for many less experienced GIS users.  I have edited my question.

Comment: Another question asking the same: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100338/is-there-a-raster2pgsql-gui

Comment: Ok just so I understand.  I would compile the same/similar script in .net or c# to create an exe?

Comment: So there is nothing that you know of that is currently available that I could use?